# I called a css that belong to another html. how is that?

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript, ionic3

I work on the Ionic 3 with angular 4. Each HTML file has its CSS file. Sometimes, I called in the HTML a case that is linked to another HTML.
I understand that this CSS class is injected into the main.js

Example of arboressance:
page1.hmtl
page1.css
page1.ts

page2.html
page2.css
page2.ts

I called a CSS from page1.css to page2.html.

**My question is** : Is this behaviour linked to the order of the ts declared on the app.module.ts?

```
page1 {
    .marginForEmplacement{
      margin-left: -5px!important;
    }
}
```

page2.html

```
<div class="marginForEmplacement"> some text </div>
```

Comment: We need to see more of your html code, can you link it - or make a codepen ?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to complicate the situation?That is why Ionic team has given the `app.scss` file. Just put your `shared` or `global` `CSS` details on that file and use wherever the places throughout the app. So simple no?

*app.scss*

```
.marginForEmplacement {
   margin-left: -5px;
}
```

*page2.html*

```
<div class="marginForEmplacement"> some text </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The question isn't entirely clear but an Angular component can have multiple style sheets imported into a component, see **styleUrls**.  This would take precedence over the global stylesheets.  This is just an example but could be a cause of the problem. [See documentation here](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles).

```
@Component({
   selector: 'app-root',
   template: `
     <h1 class="sheet1-h1-header'>Tour of Heroes</h1>
     <app-hero-main [hero]="hero" class="sheet2-wrapper'></app-hero-main>
   `,
   styleUrls: ['./sheet1.css',  './sheet2.css']
})
export class HeroAppComponent {
/* . . . */
}
```